# What is this heavy red LEGO piece with no obvious connectors?

Tags: part-identification, boat

[image: Picture of piece]

I got a bulk box of LEGO on eBay and this was in it. It has the LEGO logo at either end but the pegs at the bottom don’t connect to anything. It’s heavy, like a battery, but no connectors and it doesn’t come apart. It doesn’t appear to be magnetic. Any ideas?

Comment: Keel for red ships.  I had several of those in the early 70'es.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to reverse the duplicate direction, since the other question is about a broken version of this piece.

Answer (score 13):

It's a [Boat Keel Weighted 8 x 2 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x149&idColor=5#T=C&C=5).

Comment: Which attaches to the bottom of a boat hull, providing sub-surface ballast necessary to keep the boat steady. There are also [weighted bricks](http://bricker.info/parts/73090a/) one may use in the hold of the larger cargo hull, though those are often used on trains.

Comment: +1, I had that boat as a kid! Totally forgot about it but instantly recognized the part. :)

Answer (score 3):

I second Henrik's answer: I immediately recognize this part of this boat I used to play in my bath a lot with when I was a kid:
[image: Lego boat 1973]